# How Does HTTP Response get sent back to correct Client in TCP?

Tags: sockets, http, tcp

I trying to understand how a HTTP server ensures the correct response is sent back to the correct client.

At a very high level:

1. At the TCP layer of the server implementation, some ServerSocket (listening on the host:port that the request was addressed to) creates a 'client socket' to handle the request
2. (if we assume its a threaded server) - a thread is allocated in the application and the work gets done

Questions:-

A.) Does the Response have to go back through the same Socket that handled the Request ?

B.) If Yes, how is the Response mapped to the same socket that handled the Request ?

C.) Is it the socket's responsibility to maintain the Client IP/host that the response packets need to get addressed back to, or is it the HTTP Headers which maintain this information and which is then used to address the response back to the correct client?

If the HTTP Header info is used to route the Response back to the calling client, then I assume the Response does not necessarily have to be handled by the same socket that handled the associated Request

Any help is much appreciated.
James

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Sockets are bi-directional.**

When the ServerSocket receives a new connection, it creates a new Socket and hands it to the thread that will handle the request.  This socket is already connected and supports two-way communication.  This thread will then send the response back through this socket, which will cause it to be routed back to the connected client.  The worker thread does not explicitly need to know the IP/host of the other end because the socket is bi-directional.  It just needs to send its response through the socket and close the connection when it is done.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Erick. So then it sounds like the same socket that handled the request HAS to handle the response - I guess because this socket is what has the details of the calling Client?

What about in the Asynchronous model, whereby the thread that handled the Request (A) is not necessarily the thread that creates the response (B) - does this mean that threads need to share the details of the socket that is awaiting the response message?

Comment: Yes, the same socket must be used for both receiving the request and sending the response. The threading doesn't matter.  One thread could read the request, hand it off to another thread for processing, and hand it off to another thread for responding. What is important is that the same socket must be used from beginning to end.  All of the necessary routing information is stored inside of that socket, you just have to read from it and write to it as needed.

Comment: Remy, thanks for adding to this. Im still not clear on the mechanism behind how a Response is tied to the socket though. In the non-blocking model, we might call a remote web service as part of servicing the request and at this point have no threads waiting around for this response. When the web service response comes back and a thread gets assigned to deal with it, how does the response get mapped back to the original socket?

Comment: Whatever assigns a thread to the response must also manage the sockets and pass the right one into the handler. This is one of the reasons web servers have so many configuration parameters of thread count, timeout values, etc. Every application needs to be tweaked to handle the unique performance demands of the work process.

Comment: Thanks Erick. Sorry I cant vote up since Im a newbie. Will come back and vote you up once I have a few more points :)